# Is there a word for near the tip of an object?

Tags: word-choice, adverb-position, image-identification, adjective-position

I am designing a device with two similar components close to its tip, see below. I need some descriptors to tell the two components apart. What would be the best words to describe the positions? Something to distinguish closer-to-the-tip and slightly-further-to-the-tip.

[image]

Comment: Closest to, and furthest from, the tip?

Comment: That’s beside the point.

Comment: "Penultitip." ;)

Comment: In the above diagram I would refer to the second blue square as being 'at the neck'. The first blue square would be 'at the head'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proximal is nearest to the point of attachment and distal is furthest away.
So in this diagram you could describe the proximal and distal component
Alternatively, you could say subdistal as as meaning near the tip.

Answer (score -1):

Component `A` and `B` are situated on the device's axis side by side in the vicinity of the device `tip`.

It may require an individual to envision the `axis` to comprehend the proximity among components and the tip.